# how to change the value of a gridview in row data bound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to hide last 4 digits of mobile number in gridview and show last 4 digits as **** . im getting only header value not item template values. how to get mobile values/item values and edit it and assign to grid view?

```
protected void gvrequests_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string Mobile = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
        string securedPhone = Mobile .Remove(6);
        string MobileSecured= securedPhone + "****";
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text=MobileSecured
     }
```

Comment: Please add your markup code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the row first that it is DataRow or not like this.

```
protected void gvrequests_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
          // your logic will go here
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void gvrequests_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {

            tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-color: #87CEFA";

        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string Mobile = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

            string securedPhone = Mobile .Remove(6);
           string MobileSecured= securedPhone + "****";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = MobileSecured;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`RowDatabBound` even fired on each row means for header row , data row (alternate row too) and footer row.

So, when you want to manipulate the data, as @Sain suggest, you check that it is datarow then our logic implement.

The same logic is also apply for header and footer, but ideally we should use for the data row only.